# HTML5 contenteditable paste special style

Tags: javascript, css, html, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable Element and when I paste some Text it keeps the format.
I am also able to paste the text without format:

```
<script>
$('#divedit').bind('paste', function(e){
   $('#textarea').focus();
   setTimeout(function(){
         var text = $('#textarea').val();
         $('#textarea').val('');
         $('#divedit').focus();
         document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, text);
         }, 10);
});
</script>
```

But I want to keep the format except font-family and color.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to go over each Element node and remove the styles that you don't want saved.

If you only want to go over the pasted nodes for performance reasons you could do a solution like you have with the textarea but instead use another `contenteditable` element that will catch the pasted content, go over the nodes after the paste, and then use `innerHTML` and `insertHTML`, or move them over from the paste catcher to the editor if you don't want to recreate them.

You might also want to place some elements where the current cursor/selection is so you can restore it if you change element focus to another `textarea`/`contenteditable` to catch the paste. [Window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) will help you with this.